# Using Differences on data: trouble with floats and doubles

Tags: import, machine-precision

Consider the following data set (after I have run `FullForm`), which is imported from a file (stored typically as 10.040):

```
data = {10.`,10.02`,10.04`,10.06`,10.08`,10.1`,10.12`,10.14`,10.16`,10.18`,10.2`,10.22`,10.24`,10.26`,10.28`,10.3`,10.32`,10.34`,10.36`,10.38`,10.4`,10.42`,10.44`,10.46`,10.48`,10.5`,10.52`,10.54`,10.56`,10.58`,10.6`,10.62`,10.64`,10.66`,10.68`,10.7`,10.72`,10.74`,10.76`,10.78`,10.8`,10.82`,10.84`,10.86`,10.88`,10.9`,10.92`,10.94`,10.96`,10.98`,11.`}
```

As you can see, there is a step of `.02` between each (and every) data point. If I run

```
DeleteDuplicates@Differences@data
```

I would expect:

```
{0.2}
```

Instead I get (on my computer, YMMV, and after `FullForm`):

```
{0.019999999999999574`,0.02000000000000135`}
```

Erk. Now, I've run into these types of problems before (I'm looking at you LabView), and so  I expect it has something to do with differences of doubles / floats / machine precision numbers. In LabView, I fixed this by essentially creating a `Equivalent` type function which, given a list of numbers, did a "fuzzy" Union of sorts, and I can do the same for MMA:

```
DeleteDuplicates[Differences@data,Abs[#1-#2]/Min[#1, #2] < 10^-6 &]
```

Is this something I can stop from happening with some import parameters, or is there a better way of handling this?

Comment: I don't think the test function in the last expression is doing what you think it's doing. Try for example `DeleteDuplicates[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10^-7}, #1 - #2 <= (#1 - #2)/Min[#1, #2] 10^-6 &]` which returns `{1}`. This is because `#1 - #2 <= (#1 - #2)/Min[#1, #2] 10^-6 &` returns true for a pair of elements `{a, b}` iff  `10^-6 <= a <= b` or `And[b <= a, b <= 10^-6]`. You probably want something like `Abs[#1-#2]/Min[#1, #2] < 10^-6 &`.

Comment: @Heike oops, you're right, thanks! I typed that out too quick I guess.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6166895/618728

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways to control the accuracy.

Here is one:

```
t = Table[x + RandomReal[{0, 10^-7}], {x, 0, 1, .1}]
Rationalize[#, 10^-3] & /@ Differences[t]
(* -> {1/10, 1/10, 1/10, 1/10, 1/10, 1/10, 1/10, 1/10, 1/10, 1/10}*)
```

Comment: Ha, I had been using `Rationalize` separately today, but didn't consider it for this use case. I wonder if it's faster...