# Unexpected behavior of subtraction with approximate numbers

Tags: machine-precision, arithmetic

I'm using the `Table` command to generate a list of values:

```
FullForm /@ Table[10. - x, {x, 2.7, 2.8, .1}]
```

and I get the following result:

```
{7.3`,7.199999999999999`}
```

Why do I get `7.199999999999999'` instead of 7.2?

Moreover, if I try to calculate the `Complement` of `{7.2}` in this list, I get `{7.2,7.3}`, which is not what I would expect. At the same time, using the `Complement` option `SameTest->(#1==#2&)` gets me `{7.3}`.

This behavior is observed in Mathematica 7/8/9, and even on WolframAlpha.

P.S. I know that using `Range[7.3,7.2,-0.1]` would be clearer, I'm just curious about the aforementioned problem.

Comment: Closely related questions:  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4818/3066  
http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5580/3066

Comment: It appears that the problem is not with `Table` but rather with substraction. The question is why `10.-(2.7+0.1)//FullForm` and `10.-2.8//FullForm` produce different results.

Comment: The numbers in question are not exactly representable in base 2, which is the form used for machine arithmetic. So there will be discrepancies from round-off when one does arithmetic operations. The example in question: `InputForm[2.7+.1]                                                       

Out[8]//InputForm= 2.8000000000000003
`

Comment: Ok, I think this is it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why should it have anything to do with 'Table' ?
Try `10. - (2.7 + 0.1) // FullForm` 
it shows the same result, since you 'denude' the floating point residuals by `'Fullform'`

Comment: Ok, thanks for the example, it seems that `Table` is good, but now I don't understand why `10.-(2.7+0.1)//FullForm` and `10.-2.8//FullForm` produce different results.

Comment: Check the Help file for floating point arithmetic, and, on passing, check the concepts Accuracy and Precission.